# Selecting a PHP SimpleXML object element that is a number

Tags: php, simplexml

I am unsure how to select the "code" element - the script below is not working.

```
$reply = SimpleXMLElement Object(
 [timing] => SimpleXMLElement Object(
   [code] => SimpleXMLElement Object(
     [0] => SimpleXMLElement Object (
       [@attributes] => Array (
         [value] => q6h PRN
       )
     )
   )
 )
```

I tried using:
`$timingCode = (string) $reply->timing->code['0']->attributes()->value;`

As well as:
`$timingCode = (string) $reply->timing->code{'0'}->attributes()->value;`

Original XML below:

`<Bundle xmlns="http://hl7.org/fhir"><timing><code><text value="q6h PRN" /></code></timing></Bundle>`

Comment: Can you please post the actual XML?

Comment: @user3783243 added above

Comment: `code` is not an array in that example. `$xml->timing->code->text['value']` would do it.

Comment: @user3783243 - Your suggestion still returns the object `SimpleXMLElement Object([0] => q6h PRN)` - However it works by casting to a string using (string)

Comment: You can use the magic `->__toString()` to get it to a string, or the `(string)` cast.

Comment: @DropHit Most likely, the `var_dump($simplexmlobject)` outputs information from the class magic method `__debuginfo()`. If one would attempt to `echo` a class, the magic method `__tostring()` is called (if it exists) to return a simple string, all handled internally within SimpleXML.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I worked around this by using json_decode then json_encode however it feels "hacky" to me so if others might suggest a better approach - have at it.

```
$get_timing_code = json_decode(json_encode($reply->timing->code), true);
$med_order_data['timingCode'] = $get_timing_code['0']['0']['@attributes']['value'];
```

Another option using a modification of @Xorifelse answer looks like this:

`$med_order_data['timingCode'] = (string) $reply->timing->code->text[0]->attributes()->value;`

This works as well:
 `$med_order_data['timingCode'] = (string) $reply->timing->code->code->text['value'];`

Comment: Please don't use the JSON hack, you will regret it later. And `->code->code` won't work with your sample XML, because there is no extra `<code>` element inside the `<code>` element.

Comment: They all work so far (including ->code->code) however the second option is the best IMHO.

Answer (score 1):

What about just using an XML parser?

```
$str = '<Bundle xmlns="http://hl7.org/fhir"><timing><code><text value="q6h PRN" /></code></timing></Bundle>';
$xml = simplexml_load_string($str);

foreach($xml->timing->code->text[0]->attributes() as $a => $b) {
  echo "my key is '$a' and the value is '$b'";
}
```

But since it's a singular value:

```
echo $xml->timing->code->text[0]->attributes(); // echo the value of the first attribute of text, can be used in iteration.
echo $xml->timing->code->text['value'];         // This uses the first element found and gets the value attribute.
echo $xml->timing->code->text[0]['value'];      // This uses the first element found and make sure the first "text" element is used to get the value attribute from.
```

Will also suffice.

Comment: Already using simplexml_load_string :) to get this into a SimpleXML object. Your code still returns the object `SimpleXMLElement Object([@attributes] => Array(                                    [value] => Daily))` and not the value. HOWEVER see my updated answer to include your suggestion slightly modified.

Comment: Yes, it will print that its an object using `var_dump()`. However if you echo the value, that object will be cast into a string resulting in the value you want, automatically.

Comment: Two notes: there's no "raw array data" involved, they're all objects; and there's no *functional* difference between using `->text['value']` and `->text[0]['value']`, both will work with multiples, but you might consider one more readable than the other.

Answer (score 0):

If the XML is as written:

```
<Bundle xmlns="http://hl7.org/fhir">
    <timing>
        <code>
            <text value="q6h PRN" />
        </code>
    </timing>
</Bundle>
```

Then your first attempt is close, but you're missing a reference to the `text` node, so it needs to be:

```
$timingCode = (string) $reply->timing->code[0]->text->attributes()->value;
```

Note that `code[0]` means "the first element called `<code>`", so you could equally write:

```
$timingCode = (string) $reply->timing[0]->code[0]->text[0]->attributes()->value;
```

SimpleXML will assume the first node if you don't give a number, so even if there are multiples, you can also write:

```
$timingCode = (string) $reply->timing->code->text->attributes()->value;
```

More simply, if you're not handling namespaces, you don't normally need the `->attributes()` method, just access attributes using array-key syntax, so the simplest form in this case is actually:

```
$timingCode = (string) $reply->timing->code->text['value'];
```

Comment: You XML is close but not exactly the same as the XML in my question.

Comment: @DropHit I literally copied it from your question, and added whitespace for readability (since it didn't make a difference to the task at hand). If it doesn't match your actual XML, then your question is wrong.